# parseInt de string a number en javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Sintaxis

```
parseInt(string, base);
```

**¿Por que retorna ese numeral?**

```
parseInt("FXX123", 16);    
// retorna : 15
```

**Tengo entendido que cuando la base  es 16 , se utiliza de A hasta la  F , ¿porque en el ejemplo usa X y cual es su valor ? y¿ de que manera se realiza la conversión para que resulte 15?**

Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Eso se debe a que se está especificando una base 16 o hex. Retorna a 15 porque cuando ve la F lo analiza y luego se encuentra con X, que es NaN, debido a ésto se ignora el resto de la cadena.

Anexo referencia:

https://macengr.wordpress.com/2016/04/19/freecodecamp-and-javascript-the-parseint-method/

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Añade tu el ejemplo evita página de terceros